# Joint PDF of two exponential random variables over a region

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

My textbook, *Introduction to Probability* by Blitzstein and Hwang, gives the following example:

> (Comparing Exponentials of different rates). Let $T_1 \sim \text{Expo}(\lambda_1)$ and $T_2 \sim \text{Expo}(\lambda_2)$ be independent. Find $P(T_1 < T_2)$. For example, $T_1$ could be the lifetime of a refrigerator and $T_2$ could be the lifetime of a stove (if we are willing to assume Exponential distributions for these), and then $P(T_1 < T_2)$ is the probability that the refrigerator fails before the stove. We know from Chapter 5 that $\min(T_1, T_2) \sim \text{Expo}(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)$, which tells us about when the first appliance failure will occur, but we also may want to know about which appliance will fail first.
>
> *Solution:*
>
> We just need to integrate the joint PDF of $T_1$ and $T_2$ over the appropriate region, which is all $(t_1, t_2)$ with $t_1 > 0$, $t_2 > 0$, and $t_1 < t_2$. This yields
>
> $$\begin{align} P(T_1 < T_2) &= \int_0^\infty \int_0^{t_2} \lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_1 t_1} \lambda_2 e^{-\lambda t_2} \ dt_1 dt_2 \\ &= \int_0^\infty \left( \int_0^{t_2} \lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_1 t_1} \ dt_1 \right)\lambda_2 e^{-\lambda_2 t_2} \ dt_2 \\ &= \int_0^\infty (1 - e^{-\lambda_1 t_2}) \lambda_2e^{-\lambda t_2} \ dt_2 \\ &= 1 - \int_0^\infty \lambda_2 e^{-(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)t_2} \ dt_2 \\ &= 1 - \dfrac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2} \\ &= \dfrac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2} \end{align}$$

I have the following questions about this:

1. Why do we require $T_1$ and $T_2$ to be independent in order to construct the joint PDF?
2. My multiple integral knowledge is rusty. Why do we go over the region $\int_0^\infty \int_0^{t_2}$? Why is the second integral from $0$ to $t_2$? What happened to $t_1$? Why $\int_0^\infty$ for the first integral?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Answer (score 2):

Q1. Assuming independence makes it possible that we can compute the joint pdf. If we did not assume independence then we would need the joint pdf. So, in our case the joint pdf is given by the marginal pdf's and the assumption of independence. In this case the joint pdf is the product of the marginals.

Q2. I created the little drawing below:

[image]

The dotted area is the domain in which the $$T_1<T_2$$ event occurs.

In order to calculate the probability of the same, we have to integrate the joint pdf over the dotted region. It is clear that we have to integrate from zero to the infinity with respect to $t_2$. This will be the outer integral. If $t_2$ is fixed then we will have to integrate the joint pdf from zero to $t_2$ because $t_1=t_2$ at the border of the dotted region.. This will be the inner integral. So $t_1$ is not missing: it is in $t_2$.

Answer (score 1):

1)

It is not so much a "requirement" but more a fortunate coincidence that we are only interested in this special case that is characterized by independence.

If $T_1$ and $T_2$ are independent then we are capable to find the joint PDF (as product of the PDF's of $T_1$ and $T_2$).

If there is no independence then we simply cannot calculate $P(T_1<T_2)$ unless the joint PDF is one of our data.

---

2)

Let $u:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}$ be the function prescribed by
$\left(x,y\right)\mapsto1$ if $x<y$ and $\left(x,y\right)\mapsto0$
otherwise.

Then:

$$P\left(T_{1}<T_{2}\right)=\mathbb{E}u\left(T_{1},T_{2}\right)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}u\left(t_{1},t_{2}\right)f_{\left(T_{1},T_{2}\right)}\left(t_{1},t_{2}\right)dt_{1}dt_{2}=$$$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}u\left(t_{1},t_{2}\right)f_{\left(T_{1},T_{2}\right)}\left(t_{1},t_{2}\right)dt_{1}dt_{2}$$

The first equality is an application of the general rule $P(A)=\mathbb E\mathbf1_A$ where $\mathbf1_A$ denotes the indicator function of event $A$.

The second equality is nothing more than a definition of expectation.

The third equality rest on the fact that $f_{\left(T_{1},T_{2}\right)}\left(t_{1},t_{2}\right)=0$
if $t_{1}<0$ or $t_{2}<0$.

Moreover we have: $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}u\left(t_{1},t_{2}\right)f_{\left(T_{1},T_{2}\right)}\left(t_{1},t_{2}\right)dt_{1}dt_{2}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{t_{2}}f_{\left(T_{1},T_{2}\right)}\left(t_{1},t_{2}\right)dt_{1}dt_{2}$$
because of the properties of function $u\left(t_{1},t_{2}\right)$: it
takes value $1$ if $t_{1}<t_{2}$ and value $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. "find the PDF of the joint PDF" sounds a bit weird; do you mean "find the joint PDF"? Otherwise, I'm not sure how a joint PDF can itself have a PDF, since a PDF is a property of a random variable?

Comment: Yes, that was indeed a wrong statement (copying/pasting mistake). Repaired now.